# Need to use list in Javascript which is set in action class

Tags: struts2, struts2-jquery

I am creating double select box in **struts2**, when I select country in the first select box, it will fetch the city according to country in second select box. In my `onchange event` JS function of the first select box, I am passing selected value and sending a data to action by using the ajax send method, based on the fact I am creating a city list in my action class method. So how can I access the list in Javascript so that I can set it for second select box?

Here is my code:

```
<script>
function loadCity(str) {
  var xmlhttp;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "loadcity.action?country=" + str, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
  var dat = document.getElementById("cityList").value.toString();
  window.alert(dat);
} 
</script>                                                                                      

<s:select name="country" id="country" list="countryList" label="country" onchange="loadCity(this.value)">
</s:select>
<s:select name="city" label="City" id="cityList" list="cityList">
</s:select>
```

Here is my action class  method:

```
public String loadcity() {
  cityList = new ArrayList();
  cityList.add("New Delhi");
  cityList.add("Mumbai");
  cityList.add("Moradabad");
  setCityList(cityList);
  return NONE;
}
```

Here `cityList` is having correct value but when I am using it in my JS function, it is showing as `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide much information, but: returning `NONE` from an action method means that no further processing will occur and no result will be returned.

You're not actually *doing* anything that would cause the second select box to be modified, either; if you want to roll your own Ajax-based double-select you need to write the JavaScript that will actually *do* something with the results of the action. There are countless examples of how to do this.

You'll probably want to use a JSON result, btw, to make things a little easier.

Easier yet, use the [S2 jQuery plugin](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/), which includes an [example of an Ajax-based double select](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/SelectTag#A_simple_Doubleselect_with_Topics).

IMO doing Ajax by hand in raw JS is an exercise in futility.